# How to load gltf Model in Babylonjs Reactjs project

Tags: reactjs, gltf, babylonjs, 3d-model

I am using Babylonjs in Reactjs.

I have successfully loaded .babylon model but I want to load .gltf model in Reactjs

How can I load .gltf file model in Babylon reactjs.

here is the code snippet

```
 loadModels = () => {
    let loader = new AssetsManager(this.scene)   
    let loadModel = loader.addMeshTask("test", "", "", "model.babylon")
    loadModel.onSuccess = ( t ) => {
       // do some code
       // .....
    }
    return loader
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AssetsManager.addMeshTask eventually calls SceneLoader.ImportMesh which is very similar to SceneLoader.Append. so addMeshTask can load gltf file.
One thing you will need to make sure that you added the reference of gltf loader.
when I import babylonjs-loaders

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import 'babylonjs-loaders';
....
```

then addMeshTask successfully import gltf file.